# Несвязное множество

Tags: python, c#, c++, алгоритм

Помогите написать программу:
Пусть задан некоторый неориентированный вершинно-взвешенный граф , состоящий из вершин и ребер, при этом каждая вершина характеризуется натуральным числом из множества , соответствующим «ценности» вершины.

Смежными называются вершины, имеющие общее ребро.

Несвязным множеством вершин называется такое подмножество вершин , что никакие две вершины из этого множества не являются смежными.

Ценностью множества вершин называется сумма ценностей всех вершин, входящих в это множество.

Задача

Ваша задача – выбрать из заданного графа несвязное множество вершин таким образом, чтобы ценность данного множества была как можно больше.

Технический регламент

> <Число вершин>
>
> <Ценность первой вершины> <Ценность второй вершины> … <Ценность
> последней вершины>
>
> <Число ребер>
>
> <Первая вершина первого ребра> <Вторая вершина первого ребра>
>
> <Первая вершина второго ребра> <Вторая вершина второго ребра>
>
> <Первая вершина третьего ребра> <Вторая вершина третьего ребра>
>
> ответ
>
> <Первая вершина последнего ребра> <Вторая вершина последнего ребра>
>
> <Число выбранных вершин>
>
> <Номер первой выбранной вершины> <Номер второй выбранной вершины> …
> <Номер последней выбранной вершины>
>
> Обратите внимание на тот факт, что вершины нумеруются с единицы
>
> Для уточнения деталей обратитесь к примеру.
>
> Вот пример
>
> - 5
> - 10 6 6 1 1
> - 4
> - 1 2
> - 3 1
> - 3 5
> - 1 4
>
> Ответ:
>
> - 2
> - 1 5

Comment: 1. выбери конкретный язык, а не целую связку разных языков. Здесь гадать на каком языке тебе нужно никто не будет. 2. делай попытки самому сделать. За тебя здесь делать никто не будет твою задачу. Хочешь что бы сделали за тебя - есть более подходящие ресурсы для этого -- бижржи фриланса. SO не является биржей фриланса.

Comment: @Andrew я смогу разобраться в 3 языках, которые указал, я не прошу полностью написать программу, а прошу подсказать, логику приложения, даже без кода

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перебираете все максимальные по включению независимые множества вершин, например, с помощью [алгоритма Брона-Кербоша](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0), и находите наиболее ценное из них.

Вот, например, что есть в `networkx`: [find_cliques(G)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques) (работает на графе, дополнительному к данному)

На буржуйском это называется maxim**al** independent sets (не maximum). Отличие в том, что maximum independent set подразумевает максимальное количество включённых вершин (для конкретного графа это определённое число), а maximal independent sets могут содержать разное количество вершин - главное, что каждый из них не является подмножествами какого-то другого независимого множества.